# MySQL field not recognized

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I create a field based on some data like this:

```
SELECT 

id as ID, 
name as NAME, 
percent as PERCENT, 
hits AS HITS,
(30 * PERCENT) / 100 AS MAX_HITS_ALLOWED

FROM `table` 

WHERE MAX_HITS_ALLOWED > 10
```

I get the following error:

> Unknown column 'MAX_HITS_ALLOWED' in 'where clause'

It has to be a field from the table otherwise it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use aliasses in `where`.
Use `having` clause instead:

```
SELECT 

id as ID, 
name as NAME, 
percent as PERCENT, 
hits AS HITS,
(30 * PERCENT) / 100 AS MAX_HITS_ALLOWED

FROM `table` 
having MAX_HITS_ALLOWED > 10
```

Comment: does it use indexes?

Comment: @Arnial How it should it uses the alias of the select?

Comment: In mysql there is no way to use alias in where, and, yes, this will do what OP asked. But i still prefer @Arulkumar answer.
Because `having` work after database grab all data from table. So using `having` instead of `where` will lead to very suboptimal query. If he care about query performance then better to repeat himself in `where`.

Comment: @Arnial But you have to implement logic twice which is not good, because you should not `repeat yourself`

Comment: It's really bad example for DRY principle.

Comment: @Jens Blind adherence to the principles of programming as bad as ignoring them.

Answer (score 3):

`MAX_HITS_ALLOWED` is the column alias name, it can't be use in that way. Instead use the expression in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
    id as ID, 
    name as NAME, 
    percent as PERCENT, 
    hits AS HITS,
    (30 * PERCENT) / 100 AS MAX_HITS_ALLOWED
FROM `table` 
WHERE (30 * PERCENT) / 100 > 10
```

Comment: this is obvious but i cannot use MAX_HITS_ALLOWED?